# How to open an AlertDialog in Flutter by Button-Press?

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, alert

after Button-press, i want to open an AlertDialog, but only if the variable `bool showAlert` is true.

This is my code until now:

```
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("HIER"),
          onPressed: () {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("HI"),
              content: Text("Are you there?"),
              actions: [
                FlatButton(child: Text("Yes"), onPressed: () {},),
                FlatButton(child: Text("No"), onPressed: () {},)
              ],
              elevation: 24,
            );
          },
        ),
```

For my question (opening the alert if bool is true), the problem is, the AlertDialog is not opening.

Any solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show an AlertDialog you need a showDialog, so the code results like this :

```
    FlatButton(
          child: Text("HIER"),
          onPressed: () {
            if(showAlert){
            showDialog(
                  //if set to true allow to close popup by tapping out of the popup
                  barrierDismissible: false, 
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text("HI"),
              content: Text("Are you there?"),
              actions: [
                FlatButton(child: Text("Yes"), onPressed: () {},),
                FlatButton(child: Text("No"), onPressed: () {},)
              ],
              elevation: 24,
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to show native diolog depends on platform:

```
FlatButton(
      child: Text("HIER"),
      onPressed: () {
        if (Platform.isIOS) {
          showCupertinoDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return CupertinoAlertDialog(
                title: Text("HI"),
                content: Text("Are you there?"),
                actions: [
                  CupertinoDialogAction(
                    child: Text("Yes"),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  CupertinoDialogAction(
                    child: Text("No"),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        } else {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text("HI"),
                content: Text("Are you there?"),
                actions: [
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text("Yes"),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text("No"),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )
                ],
                elevation: 24,
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code, Hope it will help you

```
openDialog(bool showAlert, BuildContext context) async {
if(!showAlert) return;
var result = await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text("HI"),
              content: Text("Are you there?"),
              actions: [
                FlatButton(child: Text("Yes"), onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, true);
                },),
                FlatButton(child: Text("No"), onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, false);
                },)
              ],
              elevation: 24,
            ),
  );

if(!(result ?? false)) {
// Yes click
}  else {
// No click
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative
GetX Package `Get.dialog()`
And for many other scaffold components.
Dialog, Bottosheet, Snackbar, StateManagent Getx and Obx builder, and much more.
Visit pub.dev and search for GetX